# Unable to add text description into XML file

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I'm trying to hardcode a XML file with values. I also require to input a text description into the XML where it contains the hardcoded value.

I have 2 get set to store my hardcoded value into a list

```
    public class Car
    {
        public string TypeC { get; set; }
    }
    public class CarCoeTax
    {
        public List<Car> TypeCoe { get; set; }
    }
```

I then began to attempt and add a text description into the hardcoded value. I tried to add description like how i did for the webmethod but it doesn't seem to work the same way.

```
    [WebMethod(Description = "Return all COE tax Value")]
    public CarCoeTax coetaxvalueofcar()
    {
        CarCoeTax coetaxofcar = new CarCoeTax();
        coetaxofcar.TypeCoe = new List<Car>();
        (Description="COEs obtained from May 2002 to February 2004 tender exercises")
        coetaxofcar.TypeCoe.Add(new Car() { TypeC = "1.3" });
        (Description="COEs obtained from March 2004 to February 2008 tender exercises")
        coetaxofcar.TypeCoe.Add(new Car() { TypeC = "1.1" });
        (Description="COEs obtained from March 2008 onwards tender exercises")
        coetaxofcar.TypeCoe.Add(new Car() { TypeC = "1" });
        return coetaxofcar;

    }
```

Is there any other way i can use to input text description into the XML file

Answer (score 0):

Since each `Car` returned from the method will have a different value for description, this can't be made part of the WSDL itself. If you can, why not extend the return type to include the description along with the `Car` in the `CarCoeTax` container? This way the caller will be able to obtain the Description with the Car.

```
public class Car
{
    public string TypeC { get; set; }
    public string COEDescription { get; set; }
}
```

OR

```
public class CarCoeTax
{
    public List<Tuple<string, Car>> TypeCoe { get; set; }
}
```

And used like so:

```
coetaxofcar.TypeCoe.Add(new Tuple<string, Car>{
         "COEs obtained from May 2002 to February 2004 tender exercises",
          new Car() { TypeC = "1.3" });
```

(Also, the original `Description` is a property of the `[WebMethod]` attribute - attributes can only be applied to assemblies, classes, methods and parameters, but not inside a code block).